# How the transaction log files will be deleted automatically in Solr 4.0?

Tags: java, solr

In Solr 4.0 a transaction log file is created while adding the documents. After committing the documents a transaction log file is present in the location. If transaction log file size is large and that transactions committed that log file occupies the space unnecessary. How to delete the committed transaction log file and also will it be deleted automatically if it was used no longer?

Is there any configuration to set the maximum size of the transaction log? If is it so, once the maximum size is reached for the transaction log file, will the new transaction log file be created?

Answer (score 2):

From this question - [Solr Transaction Log Question](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-Transaction-Log-Question-td3776301.html), on the Solr User Mailing list:

> **Q:** How large will the transaction log grow, and how long should it be kept around?
>
> **A:** We keep around enough logs to satisfy a minimum of 100 updates
> lookback.  Unneeded log files are deleted automatically.
> When a hard commit is done, we create a new log file (since we know
> the normal index files have been sync'd and hence we no longer need
> the update log for durability).

Issuing the hard commit is the key to keeping the transaction log to a manageable size. You can configure Solr to perform commits automatically based on time or document counts - See [Update Handler Section](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#Update_Handler_Section) on the Solr Wiki for more details.